# Service Principals I create are not being created as mine

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli2, entra

I've executed the code below to create a service principal and then list all of my service principals. However, the service principal I just created is not listed.

[image: Code creating SP and listing all of mine SPs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran those CLI commands in my environment, I too got **same response** like this:

```bash
 az ad sp create-for-rbac
 az ad sp list --show-mine
```

**Response:**

[image]

This happens if the signed-in user has Admin roles like *Global Administrator* of the tenant, that won't be added as **Owner** of newly created service principal which can be checked here in Enterprise applications:

[image]

But when I ran the same commands by signing in with new user account not having *Global Administrator* access, got **response** successfully like this:

```bash
 az ad sp create-for-rbac
 az ad sp list --show-mine
```

**Response:**

[image]

In such cases where you are logging with Admin accounts, you can make use of below bash script that adds signed-in user as **Owner** of newly created service principal explicitly:

```bash
sp_create=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac)
echo "Output of 'az ad sp create-for-rbac':"
echo "$sp_create"

appId=$(echo $sp_create | jq -r '.appId')

# Retrieve the objectId of the service principal
spObjectId=$(az ad sp show --id $appId --query id --output tsv)
echo "Service Principal Object ID: $spObjectId"

# Get the objectId for the signed-in user
ownerObjectId=$(az ad signed-in-user show --query id -o tsv)
echo "Owner Object ID: $ownerObjectId"

# Add the signed-in user as an owner to the service principal
add_owner_response=$(az rest -m POST -u https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/$spObjectId/owners/\$ref -b "{\"@odata.id\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/$ownerObjectId\"}")
echo "Owner added successfully to the service principal."
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where signed-in user is added as **Owner** of service principal like this:

[image]

When I ran the same command now to list applications owned by signed-in user having Admin access, I got **response** with expected results:

```bash
 az ad sp list --show-mine
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Overview of enterprise application ownership - Microsoft Entra ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/overview-assign-app-owners)

Comment: Thank you. So this is a bug or did you find it documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's documented [here](https://i.imgur.com/iCxKpKY.png). Added the reference to MS Document by editing the answer.

Comment: The link in your comment is not the same as the [Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/overview-assign-app-owners), but I do agree that with the link you have fully answered the question. Thank you for your time. It is truly appreachiated.

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)